# Problema para identificar un endpoint en springboot mvc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

tengo el inconveniente que springboot no me reconoce un endpoint, esto me sucedio desde que agregue springsecurity a mi proyecto, les muestro mi controlador y mi configuración de JWT.

```
@GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Response<List<Usuario>> obtenerUsuarios() {
    return usuarioService.obtenerListaUsuarios();
}

@GetMapping(value = "{id}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Response<Usuario> obtenerUsuario(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return usuarioService.obtenerUsuario(id);
}

@PostMapping(value = "sesion", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) throws Exception {
    usuarioService.sesion(usuario.getUsuario(), usuario.getContrasena());
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
            .loadUserByUsername(usuario.getUsuario());
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
    Response<String> response = new Response<>();
    response.setData(token);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

Spring security

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/sesion").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
           exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

la primera url que solo me trae una lista de usuarios mediante el metodo GET, no me lo reconoce, solo el segundo, donde le mando el id, si no le mando el id en la url me echa el siguiente error

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"usuario"]
```